# Не получается правильно сформировать setup.py и упаковать в wheel

Tags: python, pip

## Исходные данные

Очень много похожих вопросов, но пока ничего не помогло

Делаю свой первый python-пакет

Проект имеет следующую структуру:

```
├── dist
│   └── at_krl-0.0.dev1-py3-none-any.whl
├── example
│   └── test.kbs
├── Makefile
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── setup.py
├── src
│   └── at_krl
│       ├── core
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   ├── # исходники
│       ├── exceptions
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   ├── # исходники
│       ├── __main__.py
│       └── utils
│           ├── error_listener.py
│           ├── __init__.py
│           ├── listener.py
└── tests
    └── at_krl
        ├── # тесты
```

Установочный файл `setup.py`выглядит следующим образом

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

import json
import os

root = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), os.pardir))
os.chdir(root)

def read_pipenv_dependencies(fname):
    # Получаем из Pipfile.lock зависимости по умолчанию.
    filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)
    with open(filepath) as lockfile:
        lockjson = json.load(lockfile)
        return [dependency for dependency in lockjson.get('default')]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(
        name='at-krl',
        version=os.getenv('PACKAGE_VERSION', '0.0.dev1'),
        packages=find_packages(where='src/at_krl'),
        package_dir={'': 'src/at_krl'},
        description='...',
        install_requires=[
              *read_pipenv_dependencies('Pipfile.lock'),
        ]
    )
```

wheel собираю с помощью:

```bash
pip install wheel
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

## Проблемы

1. В wheel-файл `dist/at_krl-0.0.dev1-py3-none-any.whl` не копируется файл `/src/at_krl/__main__.py`, содержимое проверил с помощью `zipfile.Zipfile`
2. При попытке установить wheel-файл с помощью pip в другом месте, установка проходит успешно, но потом импортировать пакет не возможно, в site-packages ничего не добавляется

Что можно по этому поводу сделать? Гуглить пробовал `python can not import after install from whl` - ничего не помогло, или я в глаза долблюсь

Исходный код и файлы можно посмотреть [тут](https://github.com/grigandal625/AT_KRL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел, в чем проблема

1. В папке `src/at_krl` потерялся файл `__init__.py`, добавил его
2. Переформировал `setup.py` следующим образом:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

import json
import os

root = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(__file__), os.pardir))
os.chdir(root)

def read_pipenv_dependencies(fname):
    # Получаем из Pipfile.lock зависимости по умолчанию.
    filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)
    with open(filepath) as lockfile:
        lockjson = json.load(lockfile)
        return [dependency for dependency in lockjson.get('default')]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup(
        name='at-krl',
        version=os.getenv('PACKAGE_VERSION', '0.0.dev2'),
        packages=find_packages(where='src'),
        package_dir={'': 'src'},
        description='AT-TECHNOLOGY knowledge representation language parsing and processing package.',
        install_requires=[
              *read_pipenv_dependencies('Pipfile.lock'),
        ]
    )
```